# Apply code format style to large Java project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, coding-style, settings

Recently I did something wrong and it ruined my project's code style format, my eyes bleed with the new code style format and I neither can read or edit my code. I fixed the project settings by restoring to default, but pre-formatted code resits the new Eclipse Format and I have to fix every Java file one by one by hand...

This is how all my sources look like after the mistake

```
                                                dropDat.setItemId(Integer
                                                    .parseInt(attrs
                                                            .getNamedItem(
                                                                    "itemid")
                                                            .getNodeValue()));
                                            dropDat.setMinDrop(Integer
                                                    .parseInt(attrs
                                                            .getNamedItem(
                                                                    "min")
                                                            .getNodeValue()));
                                            dropDat.setMaxDrop(Integer
                                                    .parseInt(attrs
                                                            .getNamedItem(
                                                                    "max")
                                                            .getNodeValue()));
                                            dropDat.setChance(Integer
                                                    .parseInt(attrs
                                                            .getNamedItem(
                                                                    "chance")
                                                            .getNodeValue()));
```

The same code should look like:

```
dropDat.setItemId(Integer.parseInt(attrs.getNamedItem("itemid").getNodeValue()));
...
dropDat.setItemId(Integer.parseInt(attrs.getNamedItem("chance").getNodeValue()));
```

My whole project is destroyed (30.000+ Java files) into this annoying coding style... What should I do to automatically fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a formatter profile here `Windows > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter`.
Then in package explorer view right click on project then select `Source > Format`.

You can also create your source clean up profile here `Windows > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Clean Up`
Then in package explorer view right click on project then select `Source > Clean up`.

You have to repeat it for all projects.

If you have many many projects then [try this solution](http://www.peterfriese.de/formatting-your-code-using-the-eclipse-code-formatter/)

Comment: I already did that mate, it works for the new code I write but it doesn't format the messed up code, I downloaded another version of eclipse after I deleted all my settings and nothing, then I opened some of the java files via a text editor and I was amazed to see that the format is saved in the .java file even when opened from notepad

Comment: It must work.. Are you opening java(with extension **.java**) file in JDT java editor?. Add some more information to your post and explain the problem in detail.

Comment: Hello Chandrayya, my problem is that this is not a matter of Eclipse Format settings anymore... The problem is that the format is now saved in binary form into the .java files itself, that means  that even when I open them with simple text viewer, the sick format is there. Eclipse won't do nothing about it when I change the Format settings and re-Format the whole project.. Thanks for your interest, much appreciated!!